# JDBC pagination in one to many relation and mapping to pojo?

Tags: java, oracle11g, pagination, one-to-many, spring-jdbc

we have a messaging logs table and we are using this table to provide a search UI which lets to search messages by id or status or auditor or date. Table audit looks like below

```
+-----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| messageId | auditor  |  status |      timestamp      |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
|        10 | program1 | Failed  | 2020-08-01 10:00:00 |
|        11 | program2 | success | 2020-08-01 10:01:10 |
|        12 | program3 | Failed  | 2020-08-01 10:01:15 |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Since in a given date range we could have many messages matching the criteria so we added **pagination for the query**. Now as a new feature we are adding another table with one to many relation which contain tags as the possible reasons for the failure. The table failure_tags will look like below

```
+-----------+----------+-------+--------+
| messageId | auditor  |  type | cause  |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------+
|        10 | program1 | type1 | cause1 |
|        10 | program1 | type1 | cause2 |
|        10 | program1 | type2 | cause3 |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------+
```

Now for a general search query for a status = 'Failed' and using left join with the other table will **retrieve 4 rows as below**

```
+-----------+----------+-------+--------+---------------------+
| messageId | auditor  |  type | cause  |      timestamp      |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------+---------------------+
|        10 | program1 | type1 | cause1 | 2020-08-01 10:00:00 |
|        10 | program1 | type1 | cause2 | 2020-08-01 10:00:00 |
|        10 | program1 | type2 | cause3 | 2020-08-01 10:00:00 |
|        12 | program3 |       |        | 2020-08-01 10:01:15 |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------+---------------------+
```

The requirement is to since the **3 rows of messageId 10** belongs to same message the requirement is to **merge the rows into 1 in json response**, so the response will have only **2 elements**

```
[
  {
    "messageId": "10",
    "auditor": "program1",
    "failures": [
      {
        "type": "type1",
        "cause": [
          "cause1",
          "cause2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "type2",
        "cause": [
          "cause3"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "date": "2020-08-01 10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "messageId": "12",
    "auditor": "program3",
    "failures": [],
    "date": "2020-08-01 10:01:15"
  }
]
```

Because of this merge for a pagination request of 10 elements after fetching from the database  and merging would result in **less than 10 results**.

The **1 solution, I could think of is after merging, if its less than page size, initiate a search again do the combining process and take the top 10 elements**. Is there any better solution to get all the results in 1 query instead of going twice or more to DB ?

We use generic spring - JDBC not the JPA.

Comment: You need to manipulate the response ion your code, after retrieving from the database

Comment: Hey I'm changing the response to the requirement, I'm only worried about the pagination.